# How to update in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I am new to nhibernate. This is what I am trying to do.

I fetch a table of people and a schedule id assigned to them from database. A record in this table is represented by a person object. Lets call the collection of persons as people. In the UI, I can add person to this collection, remove person and change the schedule id associated with the person. I make all these changes in the UI and send the people object (collection of persons)  to a service layer.

Service layer:

If I do this

```
people.ForEach(x => INHibernateLinqRepository<person>.Save(x));
```

It inserts everyone in the people collection to the table. Isn't it supposed to update if that id already exists in the database?

This is something else I tried
After the service gets people from UI I get the people from database into another collection. Then I compare the two to decide which ones to update and which ones to save. then I call save only on the new items. But then it throws the error

```
a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session:
```

I am frustrated. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NHibernate maintains its own list of objects in the session (sometimes referred to as "first-level cache"). Whenever you load some object from the database, NHibernate session stores it in internal dictionary, which is an [identity map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html) implementation.

Object id is the dictionary key. If you try to load the same entity again, using the same session, NHibernate won't go to the database: it will return the object from the session.

When you load items from the database to do a comparison, NHibernate will store them in the  session. After that, you are trying to save another instance of the same object (same id) that you have sent to the service layer. NHibernate, or rather, the internal identity map won't allow you to do this, since there's already an item with the same id in cache.

You don't need to load items from database and compare manually. NHibernate is smart enough to do this by itself. You just need to call `session.SaveOrUpdate(object)`. If object id is not assigned, it will do Insert. If there is an id value, it will do update instead.